# GitHub commits API (nodejs) not found when repository is private how to pass credentials

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, github-api, git-commit

I'm creating an API to GitHub commit using API, list commits using API.
My doubt is that
I have a repository the APIs works perfectly if the repository is public. If I changed it to private it gives "notfound" message. The accessed emails will not get "notfound" in Google, so how can I overcome this while the repository in private the routes are not found. I have the emailid which has the access how can I pass it using API?

```
const express = require('express');
const { Octokit } = require('@octokit/core');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get('/api/commits', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const octokit = new Octokit({
      auth: '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',
    });

    const owner = 'Praveenkumarsaravana';
    const repo = 'django';

    const response = await octokit.request('GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/commits', {
      owner: owner,
      repo: repo,
      headers: {
        'X-GitHub-Api-Version': '2022-11-28',
      },
    });

    res.json(response.data);
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error.message);
    console.error('Error details:', error.response?.data);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
});

app.get('/api/commit/:sha/branches', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const octokit = new Octokit({
      auth: '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',
    });

    const owner = 'Praveenkumarsaravana';
    const repo = 'django';
    const commit_sha = req.params.sha;

    const response = await octokit.request('GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/commits/{commit_sha}/branches-where-head', {
      owner: owner,
      repo: repo,
      commit_sha: commit_sha,
      headers: {
        'X-GitHub-Api-Version': '2022-11-28',
      },
    });

    res.json(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error.message);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
});
// Get pull requests associated with a specific commit
app.get('/api/commit/:sha/pulls', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log('Received request for /api/commit/:sha/pulls');
      const octokit = new Octokit({
        auth: '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',
      });
  
      const owner = 'Praveenkumarsaravana';
      const repo = 'django';
      const commit_sha = req.params.sha;
  
      const response = await octokit.request('GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/commits/{commit_sha}/pulls', {
        owner: owner,
        repo: repo,
        commit_sha: commit_sha,
        headers: {
          'X-GitHub-Api-Version': '2022-11-28',
        },
      });
  
      res.json(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error.message);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
    }
  });
  
  app.post('/api/commit/details/:sha', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const octokit = new Octokit({
        auth: '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',
      });
  
      const owner = 'Praveenkumarsaravana';
      const repo = 'django';
  
      // Check if req.body and req.body.ref are defined
    //   if (!req.body || !req.body.ref) {
    //     return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Missing or undefined "ref" in the request body' });
    //   }
  
      const ref = req.params.ref;
  
      const response = await octokit.request('GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/commits/{ref}', {
        owner: owner,
        repo: repo,
        ref: ref,
        headers: {
          'X-GitHub-Api-Version': '2022-11-28',
        },
      });
  
      res.json(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error.message);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
    }
  });
  app.post('/api/compare/:basehead', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const octokit = new Octokit({
        auth: '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',
      });

      const owner = 'Praveenkumarsaravana';
      const repo = 'django';
      const basehead = req.params.basehead;
  
    //   if (!req.body || !req.body.basehead) {
    //     return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Missing or undefined "basehead" in the request body' });
    //   }
  
      const response = await octokit.request('GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/compare/{basehead}', {
        owner: owner,
        repo: repo,
        basehead: basehead,
        headers: {
          'X-GitHub-Api-Version': '2022-11-28',
        },
      });
  
      res.json(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error.message);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
    }
  });
  
  

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

This is complete index.js page

http://localhost:3000/api/commits
the above is the route for a function if the repository is private its notfound how can I pass the credentials?

Comment: That looks like a real token! Revoke it now

Comment: Revoked sir please help me in soving the above issue

Answer (score 0):

First, delete your token from code in places similar to:

```js
const octokit = new Octokit({
  auth: 'ghp_####################################',
});
```

**RIGHT NOW**.

Second, it seems that you have no errors in the code and it is quite working, try this:

Token Permissions:
Make sure that the personal access token you are using has the necessary permissions. Go to `Settings > Developer Settings > Personal access tokens` in your GitHub account and make sure that the token has the necessary rights.

Token Scope:
If you modify the permissions of the token, you might need to regenerate and use a new token.

Repository Access:
Ensure that the GitHub account associated with the personal access token has access to the private repository. If the email address you're using for authentication doesn't have access to the private repository, you won't be able to access it.

Check for Typos:
Double check that the repository `name`, `owner`, and other details in your code are correct and match the private repository you are trying to access.